# nginx deny access to JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, nginx

I have a webpage set up using node.js set up behind nginx. Everythings work fine, but I would like to block direct public access to my css and js files

In my nginx config I have something like this:

```
location /style/ {
        deny all;
    }

location /js/ {
        deny all;
    }
```

It does correctly block access - when I view source on my webpage and try to navigate directly to the css or linked js files I get a 403 error. However, this also prevents node/nginx from being able to correctly use those files to style/add functionality to the page

What is the correct way to prevent people from directly accessing those files, while still being able to use them to display the page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way.

Either the browser can access the file and use it in the page, or it can't access the file at all.

You could *try* using the `referer` request header, but you'll get false negatives and people who have downloaded the page will have access to the JS anyway (either from the cache or from the Script tab in their browser's Developer Tools).

Comment: thats a shame, I seem to remember there was a way to do this with htaccess on apache. nothing comparable?

Comment: There isn't a way to do this with htaccess on apache. HTTP doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use standard `ngx_http_referer_module` to prevent hot-linking of your files:

```
valid_referers none blocked server_names;
location /style/ {
    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
    root /path/to/files;
}
```

Look for details in docs - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html